# DDL for array<array<String>> column in Hive

Tags: arrays, hive, ddl, arrayofarrays

I have to store array of array data that looks like this: `[['aa','bb','cc'],['dd','ee','ff']]`

Here's the Hive DDL I'm using:

```
create external table <schema>.<table_name>
(
`col1` ARRAY<ARRAY<`string`>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '<hdfs_path>'
```

Is this the correct syntax for the data to be stored as mentioned? If not what is?